# jQuery not passing variable after .click

Tags: jquery, variables, click, pass-by-value

So I have a simple jQuery script running. It has 2 buttons, 1 that sends data, and 1 button needs to set the value of one of the variables send in the first one.

Ok so here is the script for button 1 (called preview):

```
$('#execute').click(function() {
$('#currentImage').remove();

$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "effect.php",
   data: { action: $("[name='action']:checked").val(), source: sourceImage, destination: destinationImage, variables: $('#variables').val() },
   success: function(msg){
     $('#workspace').html(msg);
     $("#preview").attr("src", destinationImage+"?timestamp=" + new Date().getTime());
   }
 }); });
```

What this does is put an effect to an image and it all works wonderfull.
One of the first lines of the javascript contains the "sourceImage" variable.

```
var sourceImage = '20101201161609.jpg';
```

That variable is correctly passed to the script above.
A second button (called Save State) makes sure that ones I feel happy with the effect of the image I save the state of the image, and continue with effects over that image. This means the source image needs to be changed, which I use the following script for:

```
$('#save_state').click( function() {
var sourceImage = '2010-12-02-35-20-preview.png';
$('#header').html(sourceImage); });
```

I left the line `$('#header').html(sourceImage);` in to check if it was indeed triggered, and it was, so this line is not neccesary, but I know for sure that the action is triggered.

However, ones I again click on "Preview" in changes the value of variable **sourceImage** back to the value it started with, while it actually needs to keep this new value.

HOpe there's somebody that can help me.

Answer (score 4):

By using the `var` keyword you declare a local variable in the function, that is separate from the global variable with the same name. Remove the `var` keyword to access the global variable:

```
$('#save_state').click( function() {
  sourceImage = '2010-12-02-35-20-preview.png';
  $('#header').html(sourceImage);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `sourceImage` variable in the second function is scoped locally to the function and doesn't refer to the same variable.  I think you can make it work the way you want by simply removing the `var` keyword.  Having said that, you should be very careful using globally scoped variables.  Generally you want to scope the variable as narrowly as possible.  You might want to use the `data` function to store this value in the DOM instead, though it's hard to know without more understanding of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Here...

```
$('#save_state').click( function() {
var sourceImage = '2010-12-02-35-20-preview.png';
$('#header').html(sourceImage); });
```

...you are doing absolutely nothing, because you are setting the *local* (as indicated by `var`) variable sourceImage which goes out of scope immediately. The global (window) variable sourceImage remains untouched.